# use variables to define counters in nested for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm new to bash scripting. 
I'm trying to use variables for counters in a nested for loop, like this:

```
dir_count=$(find dump_${d}/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)
count_by=11

for ((i=0;i<=$dir_count;i+=$count_by))
do
    ((start=$i+1))
    ((end=$count_by+$i))
    echo  $start $end
    for dir in {$start..$end}
        echo $dir
    done
done
```

Output is this (I'm getting errors):

```
1 11
./loopy.sh: line 23: [: {1..11}: integer expression expected
12 22
./loopy.sh: line 23: [: {12..22}: integer expression expected
23 33
./loopy.sh: line 23: [: {23..33}: integer expression expected
```

1, 11, 12, 22, 23, 33 all look like integers to me! Is it possible to type variables? I thought it wasn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, *brace-expansion* will happen much before *variable-expansion*, so your code

```
for dir in {$start..$end}
```

will never do what it is supposed to do; use a proper loop in `bash` with a C-style for-loop as

```
for ((dir=start; dir<=end; dir++)); do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Quoting from the `man bash` page,

> [..] Brace expansion is performed **before any other expansions**, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result.  It is strictly  textual [..]